# Using foreach loop in JSF

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, jsf, foreach

I need to create a list of commandbuttons on my page, but I have some trouble with it. I pass the list from my bean through request.setAttribute and it seems to work when I get the values one at a time, but when I run through a foreach loop, they all seem to be null (And thereby being generated, and having a default value 0, "" etc., as far as I know). Any help would be greatly appreciated! In the added code, I get the correct values when i make the buttons outside of the foreach loop, but not when I run the loop itself. The List is of integer type, and should later be a java object (ran into same problem). using JSF version 2.2. Both logtest() and gotoprofile() prints the interestpointer out.

my bean has:

```
@ManagedBean(name="MyProfile")
@RequestScoped
```

And I set my variable myInterestList in my bean with:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);         
session.setAttribute("myInterestProfileName", profileName);


<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List,com.jsflogin.stringWithPointer" %>

<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
 <f:view>



<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSF Successfull login</title>
</head>
<body>


    <h:form id="forloop">
            <c:set var ="myTempList" value="${myInterestListYay}" scope="session"/>
            <c:out value="interest list"/><p>
            <h:commandButton value="#{myInterestListYay[1]}" action="#{MyProfile.logTest}">
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target ="#{MyProfile.interestPointer}" value = "#{myInterestListYay[1]}"/>
            </h:commandButton><p>


            <ui:repeat var="orly"value="${myInterestListYay}" varstatus="status"> 
                 <c:out value="${status.index}"/><h:commandButton value="#{orly}" action="#{MyProfile.logTest}">
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target ="#{MyProfile.interestPointer}" value = "#{orly}"/>
            </h:commandButton><p>
           </ui:repeat>
           <c:forEach var="orly" items="${MyProfile.interestsAndPointers}"  varStatus="status" >
                 <c:out value="${status.index}"/><c:out value=": "/><c:out value="${orly.stringName}"/><h:commandButton value="go to interest page" action="#{MyProfile.goToInterestProfile}">
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target ="#{MyProfile.interestPointer}" value = "#{orly.pointer}"/>
            </h:commandButton><p>
            </c:forEach>     
        </h:form>



    </body>
   </f:view> 
</html>
```

Comment: Use ${orly} instead of #{orly}

Comment: I get this error while trying to compile. 
"according to the TLD, the attribute value is a deffered-value or deferred-method, but the specified value contains a $-expression"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are using JSF 2 you should change your page to xhtml, then you can use *ui:repeat* and get a lot more goodies from facelets.

I made two very simple pages, one as JSP and the other one as XHTML. They use a managed bean in request scope. Both are working and render three buttons in a row. Note that I use Glassfish as a server, since it was easier to getting started. For the Tomcat(7.x) you might need to copy the jsf-api, jsf-impl (2.x) and jstl (1.2) libs into the classpath.

This is the JSP page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<f:view>
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:form>
          <c:forEach var="item" items="#{cart.items}">
            <h:commandButton value="#{item}"/>
          </c:forEach>
        </h:form>
    </body>
  </html>
</f:view>
```

Here the XHTML Page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat value="#{cart.items}" var="item">
            <h:commandButton value="#{item}" />
        </ui:repeat>   
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Why do you use a bean in request scope and set you variable there in the session? Keep it simple and change the bean to session scope:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "cart")
@SessionScoped
public class CartBean {

  private List<String> items;

  public CartBean() {
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add("shirt");
    items.add("skirt");
    items.add("trouser");
  }

  public List<String> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

}
```

Comment: #{...} template not allowed in text body it says :( if i use $, it only shows one commandbutton, that is empty, despite there being 4 in  myInterestListYay.

Comment: Which version of JSF do you use? Could you post more content of the page?

Comment: I updated my original post with the full  page at the moment. I copied the rest into a notepad document to ensure the errors wasn't caused by that. I added a bit of text on how my managed bean is set up as well